# Clarity on the 'tab' key, while entering input through command prompt

Tags: c, netbeans, cmd

I'm trying to write a program to get a line of character input from the user, and replace the blanks in the input using minimum number of tabs and blanks. 
Google tells me the number of blanks in a tab is 8, whereas when I get the input through cmd, the tab gives inconsistent spacing for letters of different lengths. Do I have to change a setting in my command prompt?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
printf("hellohello\tworld\n");
printf("hello\tworld\t\n");
return 0;
}
```

The above code gives me different tab spacing in both the print statements.

Comment: There are no blanks in tab. Editors/viewers/terminals are *showing*  it like it would be a bunch of blanks. Their number is depending on the settings of the editor/viewer/terminal.

Comment: if there is a tab after 'hello', it displays 3 blanks, whereas a tab after 'hellohello' gives me 4 blanks.

Comment: That's because you have a setting where tab 'seems to fill up' to the next multiple of 8 characters

Comment: Is there a way to change that setting in cmd?

Answer (score 1):

There's a reason why when you type

```
eggs\t2
coffee\t10
bread\t5
```

in a word processor / terminal, you get the pretty-formatted

```
eggs    2
coffee  10
bread   5
```

Tabs will always pad spaces until the next X-space interval (Called a "tab stop"), with X usually set to be 4 or 8. If you want to write three spaces, then write three spaces. You can use the `column` command in bash, or `tabstop` in vim to customize the display of tabs, but not in the way you're describing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess I'll skip the exercise. It was an exercise question in The C programming language by Denis Ritchie, written in the 80's. Guess the tab had a fixed value of spaces back then, otherwise the problem makes no sense.

Comment: No, @UdhaySankar, you misunderstand.  Tabs have never corresponded to a fixed number of spaces *in general*, but there is certainly a fixed number of spaces that fit between any two particular tab stops.  If you assume a fixed-pitch font, which the exercise surely does, then there is a fixed number of characters (of any kind) between each pair of tab stops.  The exercise likely also assumes that tab stops are *regularly* spaced, such at 8-character intervals.  The exercise is still perfectly doable, and checkable.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, yes I misunderstood it. I have to rewrite my program taking into account the fixed number of spaces between tabstops. It looks simple, but is a bit tricky. :-)